# When rolling two dice, which of the following events are independent of the event that the first die is 4:

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

When rolling two dice, which of the following events are independent of the event that the first die is 4:

(a) The second is 2

(b) The sum is 6

(c) The sum is 7

(d) The sum is even

I thought only option (a) is independent but that wasn't the case, so want to find out which ones are independent and which ones are dependent along with their reasoning.

There are multiple correct answers.

Comment: Think about d).  How does knowing that one die is $4$ give you any information about whether the sum is even?

Comment: @rostader yes I checked, only option (a) is incorrect

Comment: Start by writing out the definition of independent events so that you will remember it and might be able to apply it. I recommend that you edit the question to show this definition so that we can all see the exact words in which you learned it.

Comment: @david g stork comment really solves the entire problem

Comment: @rostader That comment tells us about (d) but not about (a), (b), or (c). At least (a) is obvious, but the other two are trickier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an example, also (d) is independent of the event "first die is 4"

In fact

$$\mathbb{P}(\text{Sum is even})=\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}(\text{Sum is even}|\text{First die is 4})$$

Check the rest in the same way finding a "tricky" result...

Comment: I found that for the question: Two dice are rolled. The event that the first die is 1 and the event that two dice sum up to be 7 are "Idependent", the reasonig  is: Let  X  be the outcome of the first die and  Y  be the outcome of the second die.  P(X=1|X+Y=7)=1/6=P(X=1) . Hence, they are independent.

Comment: accordingly option (c) should be independent as well.

Comment: @V01D : exactly...

Comment: So, option (a), (c) and (d) are independent?

Comment: @V01D Yes, correct. In these cases the best way is to use the definition

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) option (a),(c) and (d) are indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the events b and c are not independent. So let's check. For example P(sum is 7 given first roll is 4) is 1/6. If by chance it were independent P(sum is 7 given first roll is 4) would have been the same as P(sum is 7) which is 1/6 thus indeed independent

Comment: sorry but $P(\text{sum is 7}|\text{first roll is 4})=P(\text{second roll is 3})=1/6$

Comment: Corrected it thanks